# What would be a good way to implement index notation?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, index

So I need to calculate a 3x3 rotation operator (basically a matrix). I have an index-notation expression, and I was wondering if with pre-calculated theta, K1, K2, and K3, could Mathematica compute each cell of this matrix for me?

The rotation operator M is defined as such, for i, j, and k from 1 to 3.

```
M(i,j) = K(i) * K(j) + cos(theta) * (kronecker_delta(i,j) - K(i)*K(j)) +
                       sin(theta) * (levi_civita_tensor(i,k,j) * K(k))
```

I tried something new:

```
n = {0, 0, 1}
mat = Table[
  n[[i]]*n[[j]] + 
   Cos[Theta] * (KroneckerDelta[i, j] - n[[i]]*n[[j]]) + 
   Sin[Theta] * LeviCivitaTensor[3][[i, k, j]] * n[[k]], 
   {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}] (*//MatrixForm*)
```

The following output is pretty distinctly not a 3 * 3 matrix:

```
{{{Cos[Theta], Cos[Theta], Cos[Theta]}, {0, 0, -Sin[Theta]}, {0, 0, 
    0}}, {{0, 0, Sin[Theta]}, {Cos[Theta], Cos[Theta], Cos[Theta]}, {0,
    0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}
```

How do I fix this? I think it's iterating through k as if k were indices in the matrix.

Edit to the edit:

I tried summing k over the dimensions i needed, for some reason it's still being taken as a 3d matrix.

```
dimensions = 3
n = {0, 0, 1}
mat = Table[
    n[[i]]*n[[j]] + 
      Cos[Theta] * (KroneckerDelta[i, j] - n[[i]]*n[[j]]) + 
      Sum[Sin[Theta] * LeviCivitaTensor[3][[i, k, j]] * n[[k]], {k, 1, dimensions}], 
      {i, dimensions}, {j, dimensions}, {k, dimensions}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Consider giving a Working Minimal Example.

Comment: I have zero idea how to even start is the issue....

Comment: At the very least, write your definition in something Mathematica-like syntax

Comment: In `mat`, the `Table` has three indices `i,j,k` resulting in a 3 by 3 _by 3_ table. It should have only two indices.

Comment: It should be adding in each iteration of `k`, as if it was adding a sum over k of that third term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I was getting a 3x3x3 because it was working as if I was calculating the kth index of a matrix rather than just finding the sum of an expression with index notation. Adding a sum in there with the Tensor term worked this out fine.

```
ClearAll[dimensions, n, mat, i, j, k]
dimensions = 2
n = {1, 0}
mat = Table[
    n[[i]]*n[[j]] + 
     Cos[Theta] * (KroneckerDelta[i, j] - n[[i]]*n[[j]]) + 
      Sum[Sin[Theta] * LeviCivitaTensor[3][[i, k, j]] * n[[k]], {k, 1, 
       dimensions}], {i, dimensions}, {j, dimensions}] // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined the function as if Mathematica was using Einstein summation convention. Make the summation on $k$ explicit:

```
n = {0, 0, 1}
mat = Table[
   n[[i]]*n[[j]] + Cos[Theta]*(KroneckerDelta[i, j] - n[[i]]*n[[j]]) +
     Sin[Theta]*
     Sum[LeviCivitaTensor[3][[i, k, j]]*n[[k]], {k, 1, 3}], {i, 
    3}, {j, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

which gives you a rotation matrix.

Comment: Thanks! that worked as well. What is Einstein Summation convention?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Answer (score 1):

```
n = {0, 0, 1}
mat = Outer[Times, n, n]
       + Cos[θ] (IdentityMatrix[3] - Outer[Times, n, n])
       + Sin[θ] Transpose[LeviCivitaTensor[3], {1, 3, 2}].n;
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]